# Creating tables in aster very slow using hash table and join

Tags: sql, join, aster

I am doing a simple join on two tables in SQL which works fine, but when  try to create a table using the same join it runs very slowly/never completes execution.

```
create table trial distribute by hash(key1) as
    select a.*,b.item2 from table1 a
    left join table2 b
    on a.key2=b.key2;
```

I gather the issue is that I am distributing on `key1` but joining on `key2` however I am not sure what the solution is.

Comment: This is no Teradata SQL, seems to be Aster.

Comment: @dnoeth you're right, have amended my question

Comment: Is the hash of key1 poorly distributed?